# Why are these list items not rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Have a piece of code

```
        <ul className="product-tags-list">
        {
            _(issueDisplayOrders).map((severity, index) =>
                <li key={index}>
                    {issueCounts[severity]} {severity}
                </li>
            )
        }
        </ul>
```

where `issueDisplayOrders` is like

```
const issueDisplayOrders = ['Critical', 'Error', 'Warning', 'Information'];
```

and `issueCounts` is like

```
issueCounts: PropTypes.shape({
    Critical: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    Error: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    Warning: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    Information: PropTypes.number.isRequired
})
```

and yet the `ul` is getting rendered empty

```
<ul class="product-tags-list"></ul>
```

according to my unit test. Any idea why? I'm guessing I made some rookie mistake somewhere.

Comment: Are you using lodash ?

Comment: Can you show whole render method, maybe you are missing return statement somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using lodash, the map will be something like this :

```
{
  issueDisplayOrders.map((severity, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      {`${issueCounts[severity]}${severity}`}
    </li>
  ));
}
```

If you're using lodash, then:

```
{
  _.map(this.props.selectedResponse, (severity, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      {`${issueCounts[severity]}${severity}`}
    </li>
  ));
}
```